# Proving a first order logic theorem in equational logic with a term rewriting system

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, first-order-logic

I am trying to translate and prove a theorem, originally written in first order logic (FOL), into a combination of [equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic) (EL) and Boolean logic  (BL) (more precisely a model of [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)). The target language also permits [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) (Sk). So the translation task is from FOL to EL+BL+Sk. My motivation is that if my translation and subsequent proof in EL+BL+Sk are correct, then I should be able to perform such proofs using a [Term Rewriting System](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0743106692900477?token=9E4F95F314E0800DAE4D096413B3804806018AA01BA7AD208707D68EB628F789D83958E5AFD6AABEB11D5DD9CE0B0A2E) (TRS). TRS can be used to prove equational theories.  Because EL+BL is a sub-logic of FOL and Skolemization results in an equisatisfiable system, it is hoped that a valid proof in EL+BL+Sk is a valid proof of the original FOL theorem.  Below is a FOL example and my attempt at a proof using natural deduction. This is followed by my attempt at translation and proof in EL+BL+Sk. See notes on translation/proof below. Finally, I include a proof written in  [CafeOBJ](https://cafeobj.org/)  that uses term rewriting.

**My questions are:**

Is the tentative translation from FOL to EL+BL+Sk correct?

Is the tentative proof in EL+BL+Sk correct?

Does the proof in EL+BL+Sk count as a proof of the original FOL theorem? I am not sure how proof theoretic entailment ($\vdash$) in FOL relates to semantic entailment ($\models$) in EL+BL+Sk.  Does  ($\Gamma \models_{EL+BL+Sk} \varphi \iff \Gamma \vdash_{FOL} \varphi$) hold?

**Example FOL formulae**

At least one person is liked by every person: $\exists y \forall x :Likes(x,y)$

Every persons likes at least one person: $\forall x \exists y: Likes(x,y)$

I want to prove: $ (\exists y \forall x: Likes(x,y)) \vdash (\forall x \exists y : Likes(x,y)) $

**Natural Deduction (ND) proof**

[image]

The ND proof uses syntactic consequence where $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ means that the sentence $\varphi$ is provable from the set of assumptions $\Gamma$.
\begin{align*} 
&\textbf{FOL Theorem}~~(\exists y \forall x :Likes(x,y)) \vdash (\forall x  \exists y :Likes(x,y)) \\
&\\
&\textbf{Notation for EL+BL+Sk}\\
&x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\forall x~~\text{Universally Quantified variable}\\
&c~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Skolem Constant}\\
&d~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Arbitrary $Person$, for universal elimination}\\
&\mathtt{skFun}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Skolem Function}\\
&\mathtt{Likes}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Boolean valued function}\\
&\mathtt{true}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Boolean constant}\\
&\\
&\textbf{Translation of Theorem to EL+BL+Sk:}\\
&(\forall x :(\mathtt{skFun}(x)=c ,\mathtt{Likes}(x,c)))\models(\forall x:\mathtt{Likes}(x,\mathtt{skFun}(x))) \\
&\\
&\textbf{Proof in EL+BL+Sk}\\
&\textbf{1}~~\forall x:\mathtt{Likes}(x,c) = true~~~~~~\text{Assumption, with Skolem constant $c$}\\
&\textbf{2}~~\forall x:\mathtt{skFun}(x) =  c~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Interpretation of Sk. function with Sk. constant $c$}\\
&\textbf{3}~~\mathtt{Likes}(d,\mathtt{skFun}(d))~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Universal elim & Skolemization of term to be proved}\\
&\textbf{4}=~~~~~\mathtt{Likes(d,c)}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Apply 2 to second argument of 3}\\
&\textbf{5}=~~~~~~true~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Apply 1 at 4}\\
\end{align*} 
**Notes on translation/proof.**

- The EL+BL+Sk proof relies on an interpretation, so the translation needs semantic entailment $\models$. In general, this can be written as $\Gamma \models_{EL+BL+Sk} \varphi$, which means that under $EL+BL+Sk$ logic the sentence $\varphi$ is true in all models of $\Gamma$.
- In EL all variables are considered to be universally quantified.
- Existential variables in FOL that are not in the scope of universals are translated to Skolem constants.
- Existential variables in FOL that are in the scope of universals are translated to Skolem functions e.g. $\mathtt{skFun}(x)$ with single universal argument of $x$. The original existential was in the scope $x$.
- Each predicate in FOL is translated to a Boolean valued operation in EL+BL+Sk, e.g. predicate $Likes$ becomes Boolean operation $\mathtt{Likes}$.
- In EL terms are distinct, unless they are made identical or equal by equations.

Below is the listing in [CafeOBJ](https://cafeobj.org/) using TRS. The command `red` reduces a given term by regarding declared equations as left-to-right rewrite rules. The syntactic details of [CafeOBJ](https://cafeobj.org/) are not hugely important. I hope that the relation between the two proofs can be seen in the image below.
[image]
The trace of the CafeOBJ proof is basically the same as the manual proof in EL+BL+Sk above.

Comment: This seems reasonable, but I think you'd get more mileage (on this forum) out of formally writing down your translation rather than working through an elaborate example. As it is, I'm having a hard time seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: @cody Yes. My question contains too much detail. I might make a separate question outlining my method and reference this posting.